# Connecting to Oracle server in R with odbcDriverConnect()

Tags: r, oracle, rodbc

I'm using the `odbcDriverConnect()` from the RODBC package to connect R to an Oracle database:

```
ch=odbcDriverConnect('driver=Oracle in instantclient_12_2;server=10.1.010.101,1010;database=dbname;uid=XXXXX;pwd=XXXXX')
```

I get the following error messages:

```
1: In odbcDriverConnect("driver=Oracle in instantclient_12_2;server=10.1.010.101,1010;uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code 12560, message [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

2: In odbcDriverConnect("driver=Oracle in instantclient_12_2;server=10.1.010.101,1010;uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

The connection does work perfectly fine though when I set up a DSN and use the `odbcConnect()` function:

```
ch=odbcConnect("dsn_name",uid="xxxx",pwd="xxxx")
```

Comment: Please post the DSN so we see its contents. The *driver* and *server* params in connection string do not look correct and *database* is usually not specified with Oracle but SID or service name.

Comment: @Parfait The driver param is the same as the option when setting up my DSN. The server is the IP address, the last 4 digits being the port. I tried using "port=xxxx" format as well, since I've seen it entered either way. Still no luck. Do you have an example of how the connection string should look for Oracle?

Comment: There is a whole website dedicated to connection strings. See [Oracle versions](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/). Can you post actual DSN content in body of question (see edit link below tags) instead of telling what it contains? DSNs should be config text files.Thanks!